# Apache Solr server URI problem

Tags: search

I rebulding solr server after VPS crash, so I'm not completely newbie, but this time something went wrong and I can't manage the problem:

I configuring Apache Solr to use with Drupal. Acoording to may manuals Solr server URI should look like
**xx.xx.xx.xx:8983/solr/corename**

but my Solr ULR looks like

**xx.xx.xx.xx:8983/solr/#/~cores/corename**

However, Drupal reports "The Solr server could be reached", but when indexing I get errors:

1. SearchApiException while deleting items from server New SOLR server:
   "400" Status: Bad Request HTTP Status 400 - HTTP method POST is not
   supported by this URL The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
2. SearchApiException: Could not index items since important pending
   server tasks could not be perfor

med.

System info: Ubuntu 14, solr 4.7.2, tomcat 7

Comment: You did not say which Solr module for Drupal you are using.

Comment: I wonder why it has been accepted an answer given a year later than another one, and that essentially says the same thing as the older one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL that the Drupal modules need is different than the one on which you browse the Solr server as an admin. Thus, for you, assuming 8983 is server port, it should be:

xx.xx.xx.xx:8983/solr/corename

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to put "/solr/corename" in **Solr path** field ignoring "#/~cores/" part of URL on the Drupal Searh API server configuration page. Then you should press "Clear all indexed data" button on index page, then reindex.

Answer (score 1):

For Solr 4.x the server's path should also contain the Solr core name.

E.g. when using default example application, set the path to
`/solr/collection1` instead of `/solr`, then it should work.

Related: [Upgrade - The Solr server could not be reached](https://www.drupal.org/node/2083357) at d.o.